# Matching comment strings while ignoring quotes

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to match single line comments (made out of `##`) in a super basic code highlighter, while ignoring those contained within strings.

I have tried lookaheads to figure out how many pairs of finished quotes are ahead, to ignore anything that has an open quote before it but I think I hit a corner and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's what I have so far:

```regex
(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)##(.*)
```

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/j4dJAi/3

It seems strings withing the comments or on the same lines break the match. Here's what I'm testing against:

```
## Match
 Should not match
## Match

## Still a match 

This should not match ## But this should

" ## Should not be a match
"## should not be a match either" ## But this should be
" " " ## This should not be

## " <-- This breaks the match
## Previous line should match

## "this is fine somehow"?
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- Match comments as long as they are not contained in quotes
- Match comments if they contain a single or more quote character
- Ignore comments after an open quote

I was able to get a bit closer with this:

```regex
(?=^[^"]*(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)##(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yYQqkY/1

But now a comment after a string does not match properly. I'm not sure why, the logic seems about right...

Thanks!

Comment: Crazy how it seems StackOverflow's syntax highlighting breaks in the exact same way as my regex!

Comment: this? https://regex101.com/r/j4dJAi/2

Comment: @AndreElrico Sadly does not match things that are not at the start of the line (such as line 7)... I'll update the samples

Comment: yes, make examples where my pattern fails, but should match

Comment: If you remove the `##...` part  use `let pattern = "^(?=[^\"]|.*\".*\")(.*)##.*"` and replace with `$1`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wEM5SG/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: Are you replacing or extracting?

Comment: Finding position (range); so that I can color appropriately

Answer (score 0):

A little bit tricky:

Here is the solution:

https://regex101.com/r/7VTq8t/1

The trick is to use `\K` and look for `two "`.

- pattern: `^(?:(?=[^"]+)|(?=.*".*")).*\K##.*`
- flags: `gm`

Comment: Oh boy. This works perfectly in regex101, but it seems NSRegularExpression (which I use to run the regex) does not support that specific metacharacter....
See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression